# Code sign error XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, i386

```
i386: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I'm getting this error and can't figure out why. My valid architectures are set to armv6 armv7 i386. The project builds and runs fine on the iPad and iPhone simulators, but when I come to build for archive/run with a device it fails. I've also tried to run the project on multiple devices but have the same problem on all.

Anyone know why I may be getting this problem? Thanks

Comment: did you install the developer/distribution certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by keeping my artchitetures and valid architeture to armv6 armv7, i just needed to clear the "Other Code Signing Flags" under the code signing build settings for the project and targets.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Settings Architecture make the settings as follows on both project and also in targer and clean and build with device

[image: Target Build Settings for "Architecture"]

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the problem, still getting the same error.